# Bootstrap 4 проблема с модальным окном!

Tags: bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать что бы при нажатии на разные кнопки открывалось одно и тоже модальное окно но  с разным содержимым(текст разный и картинка другая)!!

Comment: посмотрите официальную доку, вот пример который вам нужен https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Comment: я очень плохо знаю javascript и не понимаю как вставить картинку можете подсказать??

Comment: добавьте код - кнопки  и пару вариантов наполнение модалки

Comment: я смотрю что в атрибут data-whatever можно только текст добавить а вот как картинку??

Comment: как вариант data-source="url-картинки" потом брать и подставлять в атрибут src картинки из модалки

Answer (score 0):

Используйте атрибут data- вешайте её на кнопку, а далее при помощи js обрабатывайте

```
$("*[data-target='modal']").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).data("value");
   alert(value)
});
```